# Add new element to existing JSON to a specific list element with jq

Tags: json, list, insert, jq

I have an already existing json, in which I have to add a new element to a list element which has a specific key-value pair. For example:

```
{
  "parent": {
    "child-list": [
      {
        "usecase": "first"
      },
      {
        "usecase": "second"
      },
      {
        "usecase": "third"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

So I would like to have this as result:

```
{
  "parent": {
    "child-list": [
      {
        "usecase": "first"
      },
      {
        "usecase": "second",
        "result": "SUCCESS"
      },
      {
        "usecase": "third"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

I've tried this:

```
jq '.parent."child-list" | map(select(."usecase"=="second") += { "result": "SUCCESS" })' base.json
```

But it prints only the 'child-list' not the whole json.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `|=` instead of `|`. It updates the object rather than just taking it as next input (just like you used `+=` not just `+` later on).

```
jq '.parent."child-list" |= map(select(."usecase"=="second") += { "result": "SUCCESS" })' base.json
```